# How to install vue cli in windows?

Tags: vue.js, installation, windows-10

I am on window 10 and the node has already been installed. and I tried to install Vue CLI as an administrator on both cmd and PowerShell but this is showing the following error:

**npm ERR! This version of C:\Users\DELL\node_modules\node\bin\node.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.**

Please help!

Comment: what's the output of `node --version`?

Comment: node version: 16.4.2

Comment: Try to uninstall the current version and try to download and install the v14

Comment: not worked for me on v14 as its showing install higher version  if you want to install vue cli as well as this error is showing => npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\bin\vue.js' -> 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue'